# How to compute gt from a set of gt masks in a tough segmentation problem

Tags: conv-neural-network, image-segmentation

I am working on a task with fuzzy bondary. As in a segmentation of an inflamatory area on a poor quality image. Hence, there are several cases:

1. An isolated area is marked as inflamatory, non-inflamatory and "uncertain" by a, b and c annotators respectively.
2. An area is marked as inflamatory by the vast majority of annotators, but the borders vary greatly between them. Some of them label a small patch of the image, Some of them label much larger patch (which mostly overlap with the smaller patch.

What is the right way to produce gt mask from this sort of data?

Comment: whip the humans? just train the AI anyway, check/correct its results, and declare that the ground truth? why not both?